# Visual Studio not showing method summary

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I wanted to move some commonly used code to simple methods and document them so I don't forget what they are for, but for some reason only the getter method has a summary shown.

Why is that and how do I fix it?

I have "Generate XML documentation enabled".

[Method with summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gByTv.png)

[Method without summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34888.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, the `<Next>` was a problem ( was treated as XML ) and I just have tunnel vision.